# Collapse Column on Datagrid when property in ViewModel-Property is null or default-value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have the following problem or situation:
I have a List of viewmodels with some properties and a datagrid, whose ItemSource is the ViewModel-List.

I want to collapse those columns, which are empty or have a default value.
ViewModel.cs

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double _numberData;
    private string _description;

    public double NumberData
    {
        get { return _numberData; }
        set
        {
            _numberData = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(NumberData)));
        }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return _description; }
        set
        {
            _description = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(NumberData)));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
}
```

And the following sample View:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="2" x:Name="_dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 1" Binding="{Binding Description}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 2" Binding="{Binding NumberData}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

The solution should be extensible, if possible.
So yes, a presenter, which controls the checks every entry like:

```
MyView.SetNumberDataColumnVisibility(viewModels.Any(vm => vm.NumberData > 0));
```

is (theoretically) an option, but you have to extend the Interface/View and the presenter every time you want the behavior on the new column.

Is there a nicer and or cleaner way .. like an event-trigger in the xaml-code?

Comment: So the NumberData Column should only be visible if there are any numbers > 0? Do you add/remove or change values inside a ViewModel of the ViewModel list while displaying the grid?

Comment: The real world scenario would be a filter, which just adds or remove members of the list. But the properties itself would stay the same.
But some members of the list just have nothing or default values for some properties... so my target would be to hide those rows.

Comment: Ok, if you just want to hide **rows** on certain conditions ... a filter is what you want. See here how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15571625/2881450

Comment: Oh sorry... I did mean columns. I can provide a more detailed example if you like

Comment: You could just create property such as HasNumberData and then bind the column's visibility using a BoolVisConverter.