# Filter ObservableCollection and bind the new results

Tags: wpf, observable

So I have this `ObservableCollection`:

```
ObservableCollection<ClipboardItem> Clipboards
```

This `ObservableCollection` binding into my `ListView`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Clipboards}"/>
```

And in my application I have this `TextBox` to allow the user to insert `string` to search for specific string inside my `ListView` and I want to filter all the result:

```
public void Execute(object? parameter)
        {
            TextBox textBox = parameter as TextBox;
            if (textBox != null)
            {
                var text = textBox.Text;
                var filteredItems = ViewModel.Clipboards.Where(x => x.Text.Contains(text)).ToList();
            }
        }
```

So this `filteredItems` is the new collection I want to bind into my `ListView`.
What is the best approach to do that ?

I was thinking to move the original `ObservableCollection` collection into new collection, Bind the filtered list and in case the user clear the `TextBox` bind again the original `ObservableCollection` collection.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568325/filter-a-datagrid-in-wpf

Answer (score 1):

You could store the original unfiltered collection in a variable and then either add and remove items from the filtered source collection property or replace it alltogether.

Something like this:

```
private readonly ClipboardItem[] allClipboards;
...

public ObservableCollection<ClipboardItem> Clipboards { get; }
    = new ObservableCollection<ClipboardItem>

public void Execute(object? parameter)
{
    TextBox textBox = parameter as TextBox;
    if (textBox != null)
    {
        var text = textBox.Text;
        var filteredItems = new HashSet<ClipboardItem>(allClipboards.Where(x => x.Text.Contains(text)));

        foreach (var item in Clipboards)
            if (!filteredItems.Contains(item))
                Clipboards.Remove(item);

        foreach (var item in filteredItems)
            if (!Clipboards.Contains(item))
                Clipboards.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: The original list still exist and not changed

Comment: Yes. Or what do you mean? The original list is never changed.